# jQuery outterHeight and outterWidth find right and bottom edge of a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Im reading through the jquery docs, and Im thinking outterHeight/outterWidth is what I am looking for. But not really sure how to use it for my needs.

Overall I have an element I want to add a submenu to, on click, I want this menu to line up directly under the trigger element. But I need the right edge of the menu element to line up with the right edge of the trigger element. Which the lining up piece of it, I'm sure a little trial and error will get me there its just finding those outter edges and where they are as far as the window/screen/what ever is concerned. So I can nudge them into place.

Key reason I am going this route is cause this menu element is attached to a handful of trigger elements scattered through the UI, and are dynamically recreated for the given trigger element.

Anyway anyone know a good way to achieve my goal? Is outterHeight/width my ideal solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to use `offset` or `position` like the jQuery UI datepicker does it for example. You create your menu at `body` level and you position it according to the offset of the element that triggers the menu.

Comment: It's important to realize that position gives you the offset with the parent element, while offset is for the full browser document.

Comment: What does the offset return though in conjunction to the body vs the element(s) in question?

Comment: So unless this element your trying to align is within the same parent as what it needs to be aligned with, go with offset().left. If you need it aligned with the right, your going to have to do some math with the object widths.

Comment: @Jacob: That's right, for this case I think `offset` is better suited.